# Is there a Facebook authentication module available for react-native?

Tags: react-native

I was wondering if anyone has found a Facebook authentication module that works in react-native on Android.

I've searched and can't find anything.

Your help locating it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no public module for Facebook authentication yet. We will have to build our own bridge module.